# How to use dispatch dynamically in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dispatch

I have a codes below, my poblem is the `dispatch` is fetching the previous `userId` paramater.

The flow is I go first to the *users-list*, and then go to *user-info* (displays right), but when I go back to *users-list* then go back to *user-info* (it does not display the right userId, instead the previous one).

```
import { fetchUserInfo } from '../../redux/users/slice';

const UserInfo = () => {
    const usersId = useParams().id;

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('->->userId', userId); // it logs exact id
        dispatch(fetchUserInfo(usersId)).then((res) => { // it fetch previous id
            // some codes here
            console.log('fetchUser', res.data);
        });
    }, []);
}
```

---

**Updated:** I just figured out that it fetch correctly, its just the **Content** component is not updating.

In my **Content.js** component, I use `useSelector` to display slice state.

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const Content = () => {
    const { userDetails } = useSelector((state) => state.users);
    
    return (
        <div className="bg-basic-400 m-px-10 p-px-16">
            <p>{userDetails.title}</p>
            //more codes here
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by go back?
And why you are mixing dispatch with promises ? Is that a thing ? Also if you could show your HTML/JSX would help visualize the problem better

Comment: @iwaduarte I updated the description sir. It fetch correctly, its just the `useSelector` in my **Content** component is not updating.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add any relevant variable as a dependency in useEffect. If you use an empty `[]` it only runs once. you need to save userId in state.

```
const [usersId, setUsersId] = useState(useParams().id);
useEffect(() => {
        console.log('->->usersId', userId); // it logs exact id
        dispatch(fetchUserInfo(usersId)).then((res) => { // it fetch previous id
            // some codes here
        });
    }, [usersId, fetchUserInfo]);
```

Comment: still not working. its a typo though. not *newsId* but *userId*. Edited the description my apologies

Comment: you need to use useState to store userID

Comment: tried `useState` for *usersId* but no difference.

Comment: see the way I added state in edited answer

Comment: I believe you also need to add `fetchUserInfo` as a dependency in useEffect

Comment: tried your answer sir, but still does not work. And bdw I add *console.log* details in the description, maybe it can help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233110/discussion-between-otejiri-and-gecko).